# Position div over other content

Tags: html, css

I am using bootstrap and the page width is NOT fixed.

I would like to display a contact form div (grey box below) like this:

[image: floating form]

So the grey contact form is sort of floating over the blue and white divs.

Thanks!

Here's what I have been trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/w69j4xam/

```
<div class="header">
Header
</div>  
<div class="content">
    <div class="bluediv">
        Some text here
    </div>  
    <div class="whitediv">
        Some more text here
    </div>  
    <div class="contactform">
        Contact Form<br/><br/><br/><br/>
    </div>  
</div>  

body{
    padding: 20px;
}
.header{
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
}

.content{}

.bluediv{
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #AFEEEE;
}

.whitediv{
    height: 180px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

.contactform{
    background-color: grey;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: post your existing code

Comment: `absolute` + `z-index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of your jfiddle example, all you need to add is a right and a top.

```
.contactform{
     right:50px;
     top:100px;
     background-color: grey;
     width: 100px;
     position: absolute;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w69j4xam/2/

Answer (score -1):

Position the outer div however you want, then position the inner divs using absolute. They'll all stack up.

```
<style type="text/css">
.inner {
  position: absolute;
}
</style>

<div class="outer">
   <div class="inner">1</div>
   <div class="inner">2</div>
   <div class="inner">3</div>
   <div class="inner">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not a good idea... If the 1,2,3 divs have variable content then they do not stack in their best way. He only wants the single div... change it to give a single element (4 is fine) position absolute and the other ones `width: 100%; clear: both;`

Comment: Thanks for helping.  I gave this a shot, but it just placed all of the divs on top of each other.  The blue and white should not be on top of each other.  Only the grey will float above them.